# Docker 1.6 and Registy 2.0

Tags: search, docker, http-status-code-404, docker-registry

Has anyone tried successfully the search command with Docker 1.6 and the new registry 2.0?

I've set mine up behind Nginx with SSL, and so far it is working fine. I can `push` and `pull` images without problems. But when I try to *search* for them all the following command give a `404` response:

```
curl -k -s -X GET https://username:password@my-docker-registry.com/v1/search
404 page not found

curl -k -s -X GET https://username:password@my-docker-registry.com/v2/search
404 page not found

root@ip-10-232-0-191:~# docker search username:password@my-docker-registry.com/hello-world
FATA[0000] Invalid repository name (admin:admin), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed

root@ip-10-232-0-191:~# docker search my-docker-registry.com/hello-world
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code 404
```

I wanted to ask if anyone has any ideas why and what is the correct way to use the Docker client to search the registry for images.

Looking at the [API v2.0 documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/), do they simply not support a *search* function? Seems a bit strange to omit such functionality.

At least something works :)

```
root@ip-10-232-0-191:~# curl -k -s -X GET https://username:password@my-docker-registry.com/v2/hello-world/tags/list
{"name":"hello-world","tags":["latest"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>To Date - the search api is lacking from registry v2.0.1 and this issue is under discussion [here](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/382). I believe search api is intended to land in v2.1.</s>

EDIT: `/v2/catalog endpoint` is available in `distribution/registry:master`

#### Before new registry api:

If you are using `REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY` you may list the contents of that directory

```
user@host:~#  tree $REGISTRY_FS_ROOTDIR/docker/registry/v2/repositories -L 2
***/docker/registry/v2/repositories
└── repository1
    └── image1
```

This may be useful to make a quick web ui you can call to do this or if you have ssh access to the host storing the repositories:

`ssh -T user@host -p <port> tree $REGISTRY_FS_ROOTDIR/docker/registry/ -L 2`

Do look at the [compose example](https://github.com/docker/distribution/tree/master/contrib/compose) which deploys both v1 & v2 registry behind an nginx reverse proxy

Comment: Although the original design (https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/206) for search functionality was to register webhooks for an indexer?
https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/notifications.md

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Docker Registry available from https://github.com/docker/distribution supports Catalog API. (v2/_catalog). This allows for capability to search repositories.

If interested, you can try docker image registry CLI I built to make it easy for using the search features in the new Docker Registry v2 distribution : (https://github.com/vivekjuneja/docker_registry_cli)

Comment: to use this you have to `docker pull distribution/registry:master` instead of `docker pull registry:2`. `registry:2` currently is `2.0.1` and catalog is implemented in `2.0.4`

Answer (score 1):

if you're on windows, here's a Powershell script to query the `v2/_catalog` from windows with basic http auth.

https://gist.github.com/so0k/b59382ea7fd959cf7040

FYI, to use this you have to `docker pull distribution/registry:master` instead of `docker pull registry:2`. the `registry:2` image version is currently `2.0.1` which does not come with the catalog endpoint.